# How to compress Chinese characters

Tags: character-encoding

I am just beginning to check out how to [compress Chinese characters](http://i.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/82/914/CS-TR-82-914.pdf). It is said there are ~8,000 common characters in daily use, and 14k in basic dictionaries. That is a lot more than the ~75 latin+punctuation characters you see in Huffman coding examples. I'm wondering if they just do Chinese characters the same way as latin characters and deal with the larger bit sequences, or they do something completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huffman coding does not in any way depend in the size if the alphabet. The length of the Huffman code for a symbol is logarithmically proportional to the inverse frequency of the symbol; in other words, the rarer a symbol is, the longer is its Huffman code. If some latin letter is extremely uncommon in the corpus you are compressing, its code length will be the same as the length of a Chinese character which is equally uncommon.

The fact that there are so many Chinese characters means that more of them will be rare, but it's certainly possible to have two corpora, one in chinese and the other using latin symbols, in which the longest latin code is longer than the longest chinese code.

Answer (score 0):

The Chinese use two bytes. There's no way to fit more than 256 code points in eight bits due to the pigeonhole principle. On the other hand practically everything fits within sixteen bits - 65,535 code points.

For example Unicode 1.1 from 1993 defines 20,902 code points for CJK languages. GBK 1.0 is the 1995 de facto standard character set in mainland China, with 21,886 code points. Theoretically you could find compress the characters into some non-aligned word system, like 12 bits or something. But the trade-off would be lots of extra processing for marginal compression.

You can also experiment with a variable-width encoding but I don't believe the efficiency will not be comparable to most western languages since the Chinese regularly use more than 256 characters.

It is also worth pointing out that the Chinese language is already much more efficient than western languages. Almost every single character in Chinese conveys significantly more information than any single character in English.